# Sending selective args from Nginx proxy to the upstreams through proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, regex, proxypass, querystring

I have a Nginx proxy configured for a Minio S3 object storage server.

Can I remove some of the query params (more than one agrs) when I'm passing a request to the upstream (Minio) and keep the rest of args?

for example:
this is the request that received by Nginx:

```
/my-private-bucket/my-image.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&w=320&X-Amz-Date=20211218T231908Z&h=200
```

I need to transform the above link to the below link (i.e. **removing the extra args: w=320 and h=200**) and then use **proxy_pass**:

```
/my-private-bucket/my-image.jpeg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211218T231908Z
```

Of course I can use multiple IF statements in the location block: [Here is a sample](https://newbedev.com/remove-parameters-within-nginx-rewrite) or [this one](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,99098,99445). but I think there should be something more rational. Something like using regex and sed in bash:

```
echo [mentioned uri] | sed -E 's/&?[wh]=[0-9]*//g'
```

...or even using map blocks in Nginx:

```
map $args $polished-args
{
    default $args
    ~&?[wh]=[0-9]* ((something magical))
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you can work the other way around, that is, pass a known list of parameters, you can use:

```
proxy_pass http://backend.example.com/path?param1=$arg_param1&param2=$arg_param2
```

If the argument order of dropped keys stays always the same, then you can use `map`:

```
map $args $cleaned_args {
    default $args;
    ^(.*)[?&]w=[0-9]+(.*)&h=[0-9]+(.*)$ $1$2$3;
    ^(.*)[?&]h=[0-9]+(.*)&w=[0-9]+(.*)$ $1$2$3;
}
```

The regular expression captures everything before `&w` or `?w`, then everything before `&h` and the rest into capture groups. The second option does the same for opposite parameter ordering.